# Ways of arranging of different nationality persons at a round table

Tags: combinatorics

> $2$ American, $2$ British, $2$ Chinese, $1$ Dutch, $1$ Egyptian, $1$ French and $1$ German people are to be seated for a round table conference, Then
>
> $(a)$ Then number of ways in which no two persons of same nationality are seated together
>
> $(b)$ The number of ways in which only American pair is adjacent, is
>
> $(c)$ The number of ways in which exactly two pairs of same nationality are together, is

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ For $(a)$ Total number of ways of arranging persons in a row is $(10-1)! = 9!$

Now number of ways in which all persons of same nationality sit together is $ = 6!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!$

So number of ways in which all persons of same nationality sit together is $ = 9!-6!\cdot 8$

Is my solution for first part right? If not, then how can I solved it? Also, help required in $(b)$ and $(c)$.

Thanks

Comment: @ShreyasS: I’m afraid not: it’s the number of arrangements that have at least one of the pairs separated, but what is wanted is the number that have all three pairs separated.

Comment: Yes, I realised that.. deleted the comment

Answer (score 6):

The first problem is an inclusion-exclusion problem. Your $9!-2\cdot8!=357,120$ is the number of arrangements that have *at least one* of the pairs separated, not the number that have *all three* pairs separated.

The number of ways in which the two Americans sit together is $2\cdot 8!$: we treat them as a single individual, so we’re seating $9$ individuals, but that one individual has two ‘states’ that have to be distinguished, since the two can sit in either order. Similarly, there are $2\cdot 8!$ arrangements with the two British together and $2\cdot 8!$ with the two Chinese together. Thus, to a first approximation there are $9!-3\cdot2\cdot8!$ arrangements that have no two people of the same nationality seated together.

However, the figure $3\cdot2\cdot8!$ counts twice every arrangement that has both the Americans and the British together. There are $2^2\cdot7!$ such arrangements (why?), so we have to subtract this number from our original approximation. The same goes for the two other pairs, American and Chinese, and British and Chinese: in each of those cases we’ve also counted $2^2\cdot 7!$ arrangements in the figure of $3\cdot2\cdot8!$. Thus, our second approximation is $9!-3\cdot2\cdot8!+3\cdot2^2\cdot7!$.

Unfortunately, this still isn’t quite right: the $2^3\cdot6!$ arrangements that have the two Americans together, the two British together, and the two Chinese together were counted once each in the $9!$ term; subtracted $3$ times each in the $-3\cdot2\cdot8!$ term; and added back in $3$ times in the $3\cdot2^2\cdot7!$ term, so they have been counted a net total of one time each. But we don’t want to count them, so we have to subtract $1$ for each of them to reach the final answer:

$$\begin{align*}
9!-3\cdot2\cdot8!+3\cdot2^2\cdot7!-2^3\cdot6!&=(9-6)\cdot8!+(84-8)\cdot6!\\
&=3\cdot8!+76\cdot6!\\
&=244\cdot720\\
&=175,680\;.
\end{align*}$$

To count the arrangements that have just the two Americans together, start with the $2\cdot8!$ arrangements that have them together. Among these there are $2^2\cdot7!$ that also have the two British together (why?), and $2^2\cdot7!$ that also have the two Chinese together. Finally, there are (as we saw before) $2^3\cdot6!$ arrangements that have all three pairs together. The inclusion-exclusion calculation is simpler this time:

$$2\cdot8!-2\cdot2^2\cdot7!+2^3\cdot6!=46,080\;.$$

I’ll leave the last one for you to try now that you’ve seen the first two.